# How to make a custom Gallery view in android

Tags: android, gallery

I am trying to create a **custom Gallery view**.  Or maybe I'm not understanding what I'm supposed to do here.  I need to overwrite the **onFling()** method of the **Gallery** class, but I do not see how I can do this as my main class must extend from **Activity**.

I have tried making a class called **CustomGallery** that extends **Gallery**, but If I try and run the app I get a force close.

How does one overwrite the **onFling()** method for a Gallery View?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I am attempting Christian's solution below however, this class has errors all over it.  Clearly I am doing this wrong.  Suggestions?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Gallery;

public class CustomGallery extends Gallery
{
    public CustomGallery(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Gallery(Context context)
    {
        this(context, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Gallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        this(context, attrs, R.attr.galleryStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public Gallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

ok this got it working, thx Christian!

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Gallery;

public class CustomGallery extends Gallery
{
    public CustomGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> > How does one overwrite the onFling() method for a Gallery View?

1. Create a class that extends Gallery (e.g. `CustomGallery`, XD)
2. Override the method
3. Use that class in your layout.

Just use it like if you were using a `Gallery`:

```
<LinearLayout>
...
<com.your.package.CustomGallery
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    the rest of the things here/>
...
</LinearLayout>
```

Make sure to override the constructor methods:

```
public class CustomGallery extends Gallery{

    public CustomGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // this could be empty, but must be here.
        // since it's a view to use from XML,
        // you must override this constructor
        // (not only the one that receives a context)
    }
}
```

Comment: damn Christian do you sleep on your keyboard lol?  Thanks for the quick reply!  I am trying now.  As long as I'm here, in the xml, would I call Gallery or CustomGallery (or whatever I named the class)?

Comment: what's "Pepe"?  -->  public Pepe(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)

Comment: edit:  As long as I'm here, in the .java, would I cast to Gallery or CustomGallery (or whatever I named the class)?

Comment: Having trouble getting this to work.  I have errors all over this class:

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Gallery;

public class CustomGallery extends Gallery
{
 public CustomGallery(Context context)
 {
  super(context);
 }
 
 @Override
 public Gallery(Context context)
 {
        this(context, null);
    }

 @Override
    public Gallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
 {
        this(context, attrs, R.attr.galleryStyle);
    }

 @Override
    public Gallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
 {
  //
 }
}

Comment: Don't use `@Override public Gallery` but `@Override public CustomGallery`. And forget about pepe, it was a mistake LOL

Comment: Got it!  thx!  You stand to make some points off of me sir!  I'll be doing lots of asking in the near future.  :)